# Angularjs - How to access method of Parent from Child via an Ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im working on a SPA (single page application) application. I am starting with a basic structure, I have a parent controller and several child controllers for each of the application modules that I need.

To avoid re-using the same methods troughout different controllers via a service, I want to put all my common methods into my Parent controller. However I cant seem to get the Ng-click to work from a child controller. Anyone has an idea?

Here is the dilema:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
     <button ng-click="Parent()"></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Service', function(){
  return { 

        get_data_service: function(){
            return console("Service is working!");
        },

 };
});

myApp.controller('ParentCtrl', function( $scope, Service){
  $scope.Parent= Service.get_data_service();
});

myApp.controller('ChildCtrl', function( $scope, Service){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use **$parent** to get the Parent property value of the immediate parent controller. If you are using another controller in child controller and to get the Parent property value of the grand parent you can use **$parent.$parent**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Service', function(){
  return { 

        get_data_service: function(){
            return console.log("Service is working!");
        },

 };
});

myApp.controller('ParentCtrl', function( $scope, Service){

  $scope.Parent = function(){
    Service.get_data_service();
  }

});

myApp.controller('ChildCtrl', function( $scope, Service){
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <b>parent</b>
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
       <button ng-click="$parent.Parent()">child</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking why your ng-click does not work, that's because
you have a syntax error, it should be
$scope.Parent= Service.get_data_service;